Confused about order of executions on Assignee field
I'm new to salesforce and currently a flow (before trigger) that updates the ownerId of a case. However, this seemed to be overridden by another case assignment rule.
I read about sf order of executions but still wonder if this is the problem.
Thanks everyone for reading

According to the Salesforce order of execution, assignment rules are run after the all after triggers.
If you have a before-trigger flow that updates the ownerId of a case, and then an assignment rule that also affects the ownerId, the assignment rule will take precedence because it runs after the before-trigger flow in the order of execution. This could be why your users see the ownerId overridden by the assignment rule.
To ensure that your before-trigger flow's update to the ownerId is not overridden by the assignment rule, you might consider:

Adjusting the criteria of the assignment rule so that it does not apply to cases already handled by your flow.
If necessary, use Apex code to enforce more complex logic that can't be achieved through configuration.

